# Networking Setup and Configuration

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, firewall, switch

I have a Router, Modem, Switch, and a Switch.

Firewall: FVS338
Switch: FS762T

What I would like to do is the following:

```
Modem <----> Firewall <---> |
                      ________________
                      |               |
                    Switch      Wireless Router
```

Is that the right way to setup?

I have networking skills but I am unsure of how to properly configure routing so that everything can be seen on the network and access internet.

Switch is for all towers/servers and router is for laptops.

Comment: You will want to keep in mind that the Firewall you have is a 100Mbps switch. If you have devices that are 1Gbps, then you would want to avoid plugging them into the Firewall. Also, for your own piece of mind, disable the Router (DHCP server) in the Wireless Router to make it just an access point. This will prevent headaches down the road. Other than that, you should be fine.

Comment: Yea, I realized that but being a home based data center, won't be pushing anything near 100Mpbs with everything running.
If I setup switch as 192.168.2.1 and then firewall 192.168.1.1 shouldnt I be able to access the firewall from 192.168.2.100(computer)? Right now getting a not found and not sure if there was any thing more specific that needed to be setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more info it is difficult to give a precise answer.

Why would you assign IP of 192.168.2.X  and 192.168.1.X to devices?   Did you use a subnet of 255.255.0.0 or something other than 255.255.255.0 ?  For a small network I would suggest keeping the subnet small with the 255.255.255.0 subnet mask

The “not found” would indicate that you have several subnets and no way of routing between.   If all devices are on the same subnet, routing will be simple.

All devices will likely use the firewall IP as the gateway and then the modem will get traffic going to the Internet.

Comment: I have the switch going to the hardware firewall now. However, I do not know how to get the firewall to connect to the modem. :/

MODEM SETUP:
http://i42.tinypic.com/2itn2gz.png

HARDWARE FIREWALL SETUP: (plugging into internet port)
http://i40.tinypic.com/w98c2h.jpg
http://i39.tinypic.com/kevtlf.jpg

SWITCH:
http://i41.tinypic.com/2s64pxh.jpg